# Spring HibernateTemplate add mapping on runtime

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

The new classes and config files will be packaged in an osgi bundle.

And the service class in bundles will be injected with Spring HibernateTemplate with Spring DM configuration file.

Can I add hibernate mappings (mapping files, entity classes) on runtime?
Will hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are using annotation to map VO with db table, here is some example code to get a Spring HibernateTemplate dynamically:

```
AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
//set annotated classes.
sessionFactoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(new Class<?>[]{VO1.class,VO2.class});
Properties props = new Properties();
//put all your hibernate configurations here

props.setProperty("dataSource.show_sql", "true");
props.setProperty("dataSource.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
....
sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);

//Create DataSource Dynamically
BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName(...);
dataSource.setUrl(...);
dataSource.setUsername(...);
dataSource.setPassword(...);

sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(ds);

//tell sessionFactoryBean that you are ready.
sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = sessionFactoryBean.getObject();

HibernateTemplate template = new HibernateTemplate();
template.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
```